# Need Plugins/Apps/API to create Whiteboard Sharing, Video Conferencing, Text Chat and Document Sharing

Tags: chat, wordpress, sharing, video-conferencing

We are planning to develop web application having features like Realtime Whiteboard sharing, Video Conferencing, Text Chat and document sharing. So that training from remote locations can be done easily. The best fit for us is realtimeboard.com but we need our branding which they are not providing right now.

So, we are looking to develop our own. Just think if there are some already available tools or plugins or api etc. I guess there should be a workaround in Wordpress like we install each plugin and get it done. If it is not what the best possible way to achieve this in least efforts and development time. We are basically .Net developers so comfortable with .Net.

Please answer the solution.

Best Regards
Jay